# Google Maps for EE - Click to activate

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps

I've updated to Google Maps for EE version 3.3.1 and now I'm just getting a "Click to Activate" message in the channel entry.  I seem to remember having this problem before and it was due to a Javascript issue, but for the life of me, I can't remember how to fix it.

The existing maps are showing ok on the front end, I just can't update or add new ones.

Edit: I've updated to the latest version, 3.3.4, but issue remains.

Any help, much appreciated.
Thanks,

Link to image: http://i44.tinypic.com/14a8uo2.png

[image: Google maps for EE Click to Activate]

Comment: This is almost always related to a JS conflict. Take a screenshot of the JS error console in Chrome and post it here. That should help with me seeing what the issue. I noticed you made a post on Devot:ee. You can just follow-up there and once we have the issue resolved, I will post and answer here for others to see.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for help. Ive updated the original comment with a screenshot a link to the image.

Comment: Can you open the FT settings and enable one of the modes, Marker Mode, Regions Mode, or Waypoint Mode? I am thinking you create the FT without enabling one of these modes. It shouldn't allow you to create a field without enabling at least one of these modes, but if you use the Field Editor the validation will pass regardless. Double check this for me, as this appears to be the error.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your help.  I've checked those settings and Marker Mode was activated.  I tried the two other modes as well, but the issue remains.  I've uploaded a screenshot of my settings here: http://i60.tinypic.com/535us4.jpg and here: http://i57.tinypic.com/28be4ih.png

Comment: Hi Justin, I've got this fixed.  When I updated gmaps, I didn't over write or delete the old folder, I just renamed it _gmaps .  Removing the old folder completely has fixed the issue.  Thanks fo your help.